# Random activity

Tags: android, activity, случайные-числа

Помогите сделать рандомное переключение между активити

Делал так, но не получается:

```
Cat c1 = new Cat();
Dog d1 = new Dog();
Object[] title =  {c1, d2};

 public Object getRandomAct(){
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
        return title[randomInt-1];

        }

Intent i= new Intent(this,getRandomAct())
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

в `Intent` передаются не объекты, а сами классы. А ещё `.nextInt(2)` возвращает числа от 0 до 1, делать -1 в массиве не требуется.

Попробуйте такое решение:

```
Object[] title = {Cat.class, Dog.class};

public Object getRandomAct(){
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
    return title[randomInt];
}

Intent i = new Intent(this, getRandomAct())
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
int random = new Random().nextInt(2);
switch (random){
    case 0: startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_1.class)); break;
    case 1: startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_2.class)); break;
}
```